# Parsed value isn't displaying the correct value when displayed

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to increase the correct answer count by 1 every time the users answer is correct. However, when parsed into the display_result() function, the correct function displays "0 correct"

I haven't been able to get this working no matter how I try to wiggle around it, so any help is really appreciated.

```
code removed for academic integrity
```

If the user has answered 1 of 3 questions correctly, I expect the answer to be "You have answer 1 questions out of 3 correctly."

Currently, it would display you have answered 0 questions out of 3 correctly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `menu_option()` you never modify `count`, so it stays at 0. Two simple fixes. Change to:

```
count = check_solution(user_solution, real_solution, count)
return count
```

Or just

```
return check_solution(user_solution, real_solution, count)
```

One other thing I noticed: in `get_user_input()` you need to return the result of the recursive calls:

```
else:
    print("Invalid input, please try again")
    return get_user_input()
```

Comment: Awesome! This worked with some minor tweaks as it was calling the check_solution() function twice for every index input. But works now :D.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems:

- you are doing `correct = menu_option(option, correct)` when instead you should be accumulating the correct scores like `correct +=`
- in the `menu_option` you are never assigning to `count`, I presume it should be `count = check_solution(...)`
- you shouldn't do `return option` for `index == 5` because that will add to the `correct`.

Comment: Your first bullet point is incorrect since `check_solution()` updates the counter: `count = count + 1`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp yeah but I don't see it defined outside, plus it's bad practice.

Comment: I wasn't returning count correctly, but unfortunately this is for a school challenge so I wasn't allowed to change the function names, parameter variables nor anything in the main() function.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the code run as I expected(python3.6+ is required):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import random


def get_user_input():
    while True:
        try:
            index = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
            if 0 < index < 6:
                return index
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input, should be Integer.\n")
        else:
            print("Invalid input, please try again")


def get_user_solution(problem):
    while True:
        print("Enter your answer")
        user_solution = input(f"{problem} = ")
        try:
            return float(user_solution)
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid input, should be float\n")


def check_solution(user_solution, solution, count):
    if user_solution == solution:
        print("Correct.")
        return count + 1
    else:
        print("Incorrect.")
        return count


def menu_option(index, count):
    first_num = random.randrange(1, 21)
    second_num = random.randrange(1, 21)

    if index == 1:
        problem = f"{first_num} + {second_num}"
        real_solution = first_num + second_num
        print(real_solution)
        user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
        return check_solution(user_solution, real_solution, count)
    if index == 2:
        problem = f"{first_num} - {second_num}"
        real_solution = first_num - second_num
        print(real_solution)
        user_solution = get_user_solution(problem)
        return check_solution(user_solution, real_solution, count)
    if index == 3:
        # blah blah blah, repeated code but removed for neatness
        pass
    if index == 5:
        option = 5
        return option


def display_result(total, correct):
    if total == 0:
        print("You answered 0 questions with 0 correct")
        print("Your score is 0.0%")
    else:
        percentage = round(correct / total * 100, 2)
        print(
            f'You answered {total} questions with {correct} correct.\n'
            f'Your score is {percentage}%'
        )

def display_intro():
    pass

def display_menu():
    pass

def display_separator():
    print('-'*20)

def main():
    display_intro()
    display_menu()
    display_separator()
    option = get_user_input()
    total = 0
    correct = 0
    while option != 5:
        total = total + 1
        correct = menu_option(option, correct)
        option = get_user_input()
    print("Exit the quiz.")
    display_separator()
    display_result(total, correct)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```